# Selenium Chrome, Ctrl+C makes Chrome not responding

Tags: c#, selenium, chromium

I want to copy a text from a webpage using `Ctrl+c` because i cant access that text using `Element.Text` property. So i've decided to use this code below for it :

```
var textElement = driver.FindElement(...);
textElement.Click();
textElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "a");
textElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "c"); // This is the place where Chrome goes not responding
var text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

The **first time** this code runs, **it works fine** but if i run the code again, it makes Chrome not responding and it responds after like 10 seconds.

Any better method or fix for this?

Comment: have you tried `textElement.get_attribute('textContent')` to get the text?

Comment: @supputuri not worked